# Get an ember component to maintain state across route transitions

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

In ember controller they maintain state accross transitions as they are singletons, is it possible to do the same thing with a component?

I need this as in my ember app the user navigates around across routes but components in the respective route get initialised to their initial state, I don't want this to happen in this case.

Comment: can you elaborate your use case? May be you can store last state in controller

Comment: Use a service, as described in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620550/where-to-store-transient-ui-state-in-ember-2-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to store transient UI state in Ember 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620550/where-to-store-transient-ui-state-in-ember-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that for my use case I need to bind specific fields in the component to either in the controller or the model. It seems components are set to a initial state on each transition.

eg:

```
 {{foo-comp  fooCompProp1=fooControllerProp1   fooCompProp2=fooModelProp1 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need more context for this question, but the probable answer is that your component needs to be in a parent template that doesn't transition when you navigate to different routes.  So in application.hbs you would have:

```
{{your-persistent-component}}
{{outlet}} <!-- Outlet your sub-routes are rendered into -->
```

Depending on your needs, you may need to nest this into a resource, for instance if you didn't want the component to show on a login page, but did want it to show for a logged-in user's index page.

Comment: What do you mean by nest this into a resource?

Comment: Check out the documentation on resources--my point is that often in ember we use a resource like `this.resource('user', { path: '/' }, function() { // more routes and resources` to hold the model/state of a logged in user.  But you didn't really elaborate so I can't tell what your use case is.

Comment: Well I have a component in a route, and that route only, that must maintain its state when I navigate out and back to its parent route.